# pandas dataframe to comma separated string in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
id      name    color   age
1     john    red     20
2     smith   blue    30
3     zang    green   50
```

I want to get the 3th row in string with format:

> id,name,color,age
>
> 1,"join","red","20"

How can I do that? Please help me

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html will probably do this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell if you want the first or third so here is both.

```
my_str = df[df.columns].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x), axis=1)[0]
print(my_str)

1, john, red, 20

my_str = df[df.columns].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x), axis=1)[2]
print(my_str)

3, zang, green, 50
```

Comment: How could I get the column names like
my_str = id,name,color,age

Comment: my_columns = ", ".join([x for x in df.columns])